# jslint :test for overrideMimeType() property in (new XMLHttpRequest())

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, jslint

This code return true in Firefox:

```
('overrideMimeType') in (new XMLHttpRequest())
```

but jslint gives me this message :

Problem at line 1 character 22: Unexpected 'in'. Compare with undefined, or use the hasOwnProperty method instead.

How to write the statement correctly according to jslint ?

I tryed that but it return false :

```
(new XMLHttpRequest()).hasOwnProperty('overrideMimeType')
```

Comment: How is that trying to follow jslint's (in this case, a little opinionated) advice? It didn't mention `typeof`, it specified: (1)compare with `undefined`, or (2)use `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: true.
Still, this code return false :
(new XMLHttpRequest()).hasOwnProperty('overrideMimeType')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.hasOwnProperty('overrideMimeType')
```